# Material Ui button colors not changed after theme change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In the project with react Material Ui is used. The theme is being overriden, but the colors of buttons and inputs do not change.

Here is the `theme.js` where Material Ui theme is created

```
// @flow
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

import type
{
  Theme,
} from '@material-ui/core';

const theme: Theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ffa300',
      light: '#ffd449',
      dark: '#c67400',
      contrastText: '#000000',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff8500',
      light: '#ffb644',
      dark: '#c55600',
      contrastText: '#000000',
    },
    error: {
      main: '#A21C2B',
    },
  },
});


export default theme;
```

Here is `App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import {
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import theme from './theme';
import Auth from './Auth';

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Switch>
      <Auth />
    </Switch>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Note there the use of the new `ThemeProvider` because hooks are used later.

And here is a sample login page

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  main: {
    width: 'auto',
    display: 'block', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
      width: 400,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
    },
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 8,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px\
    ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px\
    ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px`,
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  submit: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
}));

const Login = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <main className={classes.main}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form}>
          <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
            <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
            <Input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign in
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

And here is the problem. The colors of the button and input are not changed. But the color of the `LockIcon` is changed to the color provided by theme.

Comment: Are you following https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#migration-for-material-ui-core-users you do not need to use both Theme Providers

Comment: @JoshWooding I've fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

The answer below is specific to using `@material-ui/styles` with the 3.x versions of Material-UI. These install steps (`bootstrapMuiStyles.js`) are no longer necessary for v4 of Material-UI.

---

Initially I recommended also wrapping with the `MuiThemeProvider`. That works, but is the wrong solution and likely would lead to further issues when trying to use the new `@material-ui/styles` package. Based on Josh Wooding's comment and then reading the details in the docs and looking through some of the code, below is a solution in line with Josh's recommendation. The excerpts are from my CodeSandbox so there are some differences due to simplifications/changes (e.g. not using types) I did to your code to get a working example. The important parts are just `index.js` and `bootstrapMuiStyles.js` -- particularly the ordering of the imports. It will not work to import the `install` method directly from `index.js`, because that will force you to call `install()` after you have already imported `App.js`.

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// It is important for this import to be before the import of App
// so that no other Material-UI imports happen before the install
import "./bootstrapMuiStyles";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`bootstrapMuiStyles.js`

```
import { install } from "@material-ui/styles";
install();
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import theme from "./theme";
import Login from "./Login";

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Login />
  </ThemeProvider>
);
export default App;
```

And then `Login.js` is a nearly exact copy of the code from your question.

You can see this working here:

[image: Edit mz4q046v0j]

Answer (score 2):

In version 4, This Theme Provider is not working.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

theme called is

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { red } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#06a3b8"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#ff7c04"
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400
    },
    background: {
      default: "#ffffff"
    }
  },
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Comment: Is this a question?