# Material UI theme colors not working with React Button

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Material UI theme colors with React button.

I have seen these [documents](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090679/material-ui-button-colors-not-changed-after-theme-change).

My experience is not consistent with the documentation.

I have defined a theme as follows:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';
import indigo from '@material-ui/core/colors/indigo';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: { main: blue['A200'] },
      secondary: { main: indigo['A400'] },
    //   type: defaultDark ? "dark" : "light",
    }
})
```

I use it in my component as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ButtonGroup from '@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from "../../services/appearance/theme";
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
}));

export default function BasicButtonGroup() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
    
        <ButtonGroup  color="secondary" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
            <Button color="secondary" href="">option 1</Button>
            <Button color="secondary">option 2</Button>
           
        </ButtonGroup>
        
        
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The on-hover color of the button border changes to my defined secondary color, but the main button itself remains the secondary color of MaterialUI default theme.

When I inspect the console, the color I defined as my secondary theme appears as a crossed out css element. The Material UI default theme secondary color appears on the element.

What else do I need to do to get this working in a manner consistent with the documentation?

Comment: This appears to be working on my side: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-glade-xn2r8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please create a code sandbox reproducing your problem.